# how to reuse last layers' bias in next layers in Keras with tensorflow Backend

Tags: keras

I'm new to Keras
my neural network structure is here:
[neural network structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIp56.png)

my idea is :

```
import keras.backend as KBack
import tensorflow as tf

#...some code here

model = Sequential()
hidden_units = 4
layer1 = Dense(
    hidden_units,
    input_dim=len(InputIndex),
    activation='sigmoid'
)
model.add(layer1)
# layer1_bias = layer1.get_weights()[1][0]

layer2 = Dense(
    1, activation='sigmoid',
    use_bias=False
)
model.add(layer2)
# KBack.bias_add(model.output, layer1_bias[0])
```

I know this is not working cause layer1_bias[0] is not tensor, but I have no idea how to fix it. Or somebody has other solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because `bias_add` expects a `Tensor` and you are passing it a float (the actual value of the bias). Also, be aware that your hidden layer actually has 3 biases (one for each node). If you want to add the bias of the first node to your output layer, this should work:

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()

layer1 = Dense(3, input_dim=2, activation='sigmoid')
layer2 = Dense(1, activation=None, use_bias=False)
activation = Activation('sigmoid')

model.add(layer1)
model.add(layer2)
K.bias_add(model.output, layer1.bias[0:1]) # slice like this to not lose a dimension
model.add(activation)

print(model.summary())
```

Note that, to be 'correct' (according to the definition of what a dense layer does), you should add the bias first, then the activation.

Also, your code is not really in line with the picture of your network. In the picture, one single shared bias is added to each of the nodes in the network. You can do this with the functional API. The idea is to disable the use of biases in the hidden layer and the output layers, and to manually add a bias variable that you define yourself and that will be shared by the layers. I'm using tensorflow for `tf.add()` since that supports broadcasting:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Lambda, Input, Add
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

# Define the shared bias as a custom keras variable
shared_bias = K.variable(value=[0], name='shared_bias')

input_layer = Input(shape=(2,))
# Disable biases in the hidden layer
dense_1 = Dense(units=3, use_bias=False, activation=None)(input_layer)
# Manually add the shared bias
dense_1 = Lambda(lambda x: tf.add(x, shared_bias))(dense_1)
# Disable bias in output layer
output_layer = Dense(units=1, use_bias=False)(dense_1)
# Manually add the bias variable
output_layer = Lambda(lambda x: tf.add(x, shared_bias))(output_layer)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
print(model.summary())
```

This assumes that your shared bias is not trainable though.

Comment: thanks for your help, It's work well. ummm... I have anther question: I can't save this model by using "model_save()".  

The error is : "TypeError: can't pickle SwigPyObject objects".  

Sorry to bother you, but thank you again.

Comment: Not sure about that one. Perhaps it has to do with the `Lambda` layer. See [this issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6442) for example. Perhaps you can try to define the shared bias in side of the Lambda layer: `lambda(x: tf.add(K.variable(...), x))`. If that does not help, please open a different question with more details.